# Facebook API: Access page conversation

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to make a facebook app that is able to access the messages of a page the user is managing.

My Account is managing exactly one page and I can access that page, but somehow not the conversations.

I request my permissions like this:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    testFacebookApi();
}, {
    scope: "manage_pages,read_page_mailboxes"
});
```

And get the expected results for all the Graph-API-Calls but the last one:

```
FB.api("/me", function (response) {
    console.log("Me: ", response);
});
```

Result: `Object {name: "{MyName}", id: "{MyID}"}`

```
FB.api("/me/permissions", function (response) {
    console.log("My Permissions: ", response);
});
```

Result: `permission: "manage_pages" status: "granted"`, 
`permission: "read_page_mailboxes" status: "granted"`,...

```
FB.api("/me/accounts", function (response) {
   console.log("My accounts: ", response);
});
```

Result: `access_token: "{my_page_acces_token}" category: "{my_page_category}" id: "{my_page_id}" name: "{my_page_name}"`

```
FB.api("/" + page.id, function (pageResponse) {
    console.log("Page: ", pageResponse);
});
```

Result: `Object {name: "{my_page_name}", id: "{my_page_id}"}`  with the correct results

```
FB.api("/" + page.id + "/conversations", function (convResponse) {
    console.log("Conversations: ", convResponse);
});
```

Result: `error: Object
code: 298
message: "(#298) Requires extended permission: read_mailbox"
type: "OAuthException"`

But `read_mailbox` should not be required to read the pages messages since i have `read_page_mailboxes`. And `read_mailbox` cannot be granted....

Answer (score 0):

actually, read_mailbox is deprecated and you are doing well to use read_page_mailboxes

Did you ask Facebook for a review on your app?

I m not sure but I think it s why you don t have the permission to get it

> read_page_mailboxes
>
> Provides the ability to read from the Page Inboxes of the Pages
>   managed by a person. This permission is often used alongside the
>   manage_pages permission.
>
> This permission does not let your app read the page owner's mailbox.
>   It only applies to the page's mailbox.
>
> Review **If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to
>   review how your app uses it.**
>
> Common Usage Let someone manage the mailboxes of their Pages through
>   your app.

Comment: I get `permission: "read_page_mailboxes" status: "granted"` so it should work....
With the Graph-API-Explorer I found out that when i change the access token to the page access token it works... May that be the problem? Do I have to change the access token?

Comment: You'll need ot use the Page Access Token to get data from pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
insteat uf trying to access the conversations as the page-admin with `"/" + page.id + "/conversations"` I simply access them as the page itself: `"me/conversations?access_token=" + page.access_token`